# QApplication The program has unexpectedly finished

Tags: qt

I created my project with OpenCV and QT libraries.
In my project, I show to my webcam a Marker (using aruco); when cam recognize it, a browser is created (with Qt library) and a site is shown. (you can see it in this image)
[image]

But, when I close the browser and i show the marker to cam again (I don't close my project), my program stops unexpectedly
[image]

I work on Win7 x64 with QtCreator 2.6.0 e qt 4.8.3 library.
I think problem is the QApplication. it seems that does not close completely.

this is the code of browser's creation (QApplication's creation):

```
   int browser(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(data);
    BrowserApplication application(argc, argv);
    if (!application.isTheOnlyBrowser())
        return 0;
    application.newMainWindow();
   return application.exec();

}
```

Anyone have any ideas or know how to fix it???

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect `application.newMainWindow();`. Maybe it creates a second instance.

Comment: +1 for the beauty you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my understanding you have one application with at least two windows (one for the camera and one for the browser) and I suspect BrowserApplication is subclassing QApplication. Is this correct? If I'm correct, then read the first few lines of the QApplication class description:

> For any GUI application using Qt, there is precisely one QApplication
>   object, no matter whether the application has 0, 1, 2 or more windows
>   at any given time.

You're not providing the implementation of BrowserApplication but I suspect you're creating two instances.

Comment: Luca you got it right! I have one application with two windows (one created with opencv for the camera, and the other created with qt for the browser). 
problem is when the first browser closes and I want to create a second. when I close the browser, the instance should not be deleted? So how do I actually delete the first instance of the browser?

Comment: Here you can find the implementation of BrowserApplication: http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/5.0/qtwebkitexamples/webkitwidgets-browser-browserapplication-cpp.html

Comment: Rearrange your application to avoid two instances of QApplication. You don't need to subclass QApplication to create a window containing a web page. Look at the code you reported to see how.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Can I avoid using BrowserApplication to create a window containing a web page?

Comment: QApplication has nothing to do directly with QtWebKit. Please, read the documentation: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtwebkit.html.